# How to use a Linux variable as a command parameter

Tags: linux, shell, variables, command

I am trying to use a bash shell variable as a command parameter but can't

Here is what works:

```
sed -n '2p' <file>
```

gives me line 2 of file

What I want to do:

```
sed -n '$variable p' <file>
```

Of course, this does not work. I have tried every possible syntax combination without success. How can I incorporate a variable in place of a constant?

Comment: Use double quotes and braces to delimit the variable name: `sed -n "${variable}p"`. Single quotes make all the normal shell metacharacters ordinary again, so `$`, backslash ``\`` and backticks are not interpreted as usual. The space between the number and the `p` is optional when the braces are used, but mandatory when they're omitted.

Answer (score 3):

Variables are expanded inside doublequotes, not inside singlequotes:

```
sed -n "$variable p" <file>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Barmar has the right answer to your question.

I fear you are going to use this as a technique to iterate over the lines of a file.

This will be very inefficient:

```
for linenum in $(seq $(wc -l < filename)); do
    line=$(sed -n "$linenum p" filename)
    # do something with $line
done
```

The idiomatic way to iterate over the lines of a file is:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # do something with "$line"
done < filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the variable outside the string:
    sed -n $variable'p'